# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver or com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Tags: spring-mvc, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have to query MSSQL.
I tried every solution but did not work. I tried  both com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 and com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver.

Where the problematic part may be ?

Thanks.

That's my repo.
[image]

And the database service

```
     String connectionString = "";
    String JDBC_SQLSERVER_STRING = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
   //for (HierarchicalConfiguration database : databases) {
               try
               {


                       try {
                           Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        // Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
                       }
                       catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                         throw new Exception();
                    }

        connectionString = JDBC_SQLSERVER_STRING + "xx" + ":" + "yy" + ";databaseName=" + "zz";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "aa", "bb");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM zz.cc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please share your pom.xml file, Are you using sqljdbc maven dependency or external .jar file ?

Here is the latest version of sqlserver maven dependency, 
Microsoft recently announces the open sourcing of the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server! Now you can directly use this below dependency instead of adding external lib:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>6.1.0.jre8</version> 
</dependency>
```